# Photon number autocorrelation in Cavity QED

Tags: quantum-optics, research-level, correlation-functions, cavity-qed

I am studying [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2788) paper dealing with optomechanical strong coupling, and I don't understand one very relevant part of it.

In particular, the authors define (equation (8)) a *photon number autocorrelation* function:

$$S_{nn}(t) = \langle \hat{a}(t)^{\dagger}\hat{a}(t)\hat{a}(0)^{\dagger}\hat{a}(0)\rangle - \langle \hat{a}(t)^{\dagger}\hat{a}(t)\rangle^2$$

Here, $\hat{a}(t)$ is the creation operator of a photon for a given cavity mode, evaluated at time $t$ in a Heisenberg picture.

*Question 1*

What is the meaning behind this function? I have an understanding of $\langle \hat{a}^{\dagger}\hat{a} \rangle$ as the mean number of photons circulating in the cavity, but how does this relate to *fluctuations*?

Then, they define the Fourier Transform of this function:
$$S(\omega) = \int e^{-i\omega t}S_{nn}(t)$$
which is the Power spectral density.

*Question 2*

I would interpret this as I would interpret a standard FT: Given a time signal, the FT gives the strength of various frequency contributions. But how can I understand the frequency decomposition of *fluctuations*?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136798/discussion-on-question-by-lioncereals-photon-number-autocorrelation-in-cavity-qe).